# i can't understand the order in which my code is executing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, event-loop

In the given code method .find() is executed first and method .create() executes second however in the code they are defined opposite as you can see.I know this has something to do with event loop but i can't understand the conceptual view of my code so, please explain this step-wise.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cat_app', {useNewUrlParser: true});

const catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    temperament: String
});

const Cat = mongoose.model("Cat", catSchema);

Cat.create({name: "uleru", age: 7, temperament: "jarigon"}, (err, cats) =>
{
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("cat has been added to database" + cats);
});

 Cat.find({}, function (err, cats) {
     if (err) return console.error(err);
     console.log(cats);
});
```

Comment: My guess is what you are actually seeing is this: 

code runs, firing off TWO async things --

one async thing finishes first (the find would probably finish first every single time depending on the indexing) so it looks like it is 'running first'

then the other async thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why you see this behaviour, you need to understand asynchronous code. Nodejs will read your instructions, and then it's done. When the `find` method then finishes, it calls the callback defined. Imagine the find operation was very complicated, then your create function callback would be executed first. (but the find operation would be executing meanwhile). To understand this, I can recommend the following videos. Make some coffee and tune in :)

[What the heck is the event loop anyway? | Philip Roberts | JSConf EU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Today most Nodejs programmers use Promises to handle async code, you can learn about this here:

[Promises - Part 8 of Functional Programming in JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2d7s3spWAzo&t=545s)

[Async JS Crash Course - Callbacks, Promises, Async Await](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoRJizFvM7s)

I hope this helps.